# PDF to text (multiple pages)

Tags: linux, pdf, debian, pdftotext

How to extract text from a PDF with multiple pages? I need to get each page as separated text strings

Page 1 as one string, page 2 as another string etc

Is it possible with `pdftotext` or any other tool?

I need a Linux command line tool

Comment: There are different ways to that, but you have to say what you want. Do you want to use online, offline, cmd, etc tools? Which OS?

Comment: linux (debian) command line :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the already named `pdftotext` tool, which can be installed by running `sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`. After that you can simply run `pdftotext /link/to/input.pdf /link/to/output.txt`.

Comment: yes, I know that.. but how to seperate each page to each text string?

Comment: but I send the output to stdout like this `pdftotext $file -`

Comment: You could use the `-f number` flag, it specifies the first side to convert. You have to replace number with the side.

Comment: I don't know how to help you any further until i know what you want to do.

Comment: If this helped you, please accept this answer.

Comment: its not working.. `pdftotext -f $i $file -` this command combines all pages to one string

Comment: it works.. I forgot the second argument `pdftotext -f $i -l $i $file -`